# Py.test run until pass decorator

Tags: python, pytest

I have some tests which uploaded different data (music, video) and get metadata from service.

So time.sleep() is a really bad way, because different servers and situations could overload system.

So I'm looking special decorator or parameter to set. Something like this

```
@fails(10)
def test_get_info(self):
    assert info == 1
```

After 10 attempts assert is still failed - raise Exception.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`retry` decorator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/):

```
@retry(AssertionError, tries=10)
def test_get_info(self):
    assert info == 1
```

Note: it doesn't take into account `setup`, `teardown` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's works great, for the most part, but in pytest, a decorated method will somehow "jump" to the beginning, and be tested before the other tests, which breaks the ordering.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completion, I would also add the following plugin:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flaky

It works out of the box with py.test and nose, and all you would have to do is to decorate your test methods or classes. I think it's a pretty neat API:

```
@flaky(max_runs=10)
def test_get_info(self):
    assert info == 1
```